# Angular - How to make an HTTP request that has multiple subscribers / subjects

Tags: angular, rxjs, xmlhttprequest, observable, behaviorsubject

I have an angular service that calls an API and gets a list of pages. These pages are subscribed to from multiple components. With this in mind, I use BehaviorSubjects to make sure each subscriber gets the updates.

When I want to add a new page, I need to submit an HTTP POST request to the server, and handle the response. While handling it, I need to update an array, then call next() to send the updates to all of the subscribers. This requires me to have a subscriber on the HTTP call (at least, I think it does) so that I can call next().  However, while calling next, I also want the component to update and let the user know the request has been completed.

Here is a stackblitz example. In app.component.ts, line 38 has a call to the service to create a page. Below that is a section of commented out code that would subscribe and set the isSaving variable to false. However, I cannot subscribe to the method as it already has a subscription inside the pages.service.ts file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abi4mn

I'm hoping the example makes more sense than my ramblings, apologies if the explanation is poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you subscribe to the observable in your PagesService, the component which is calling the method should subscribe to it instead. So in your `PagesService.add` you should return the observable and you can subscribe to the observable in the calling component: `this.pagesService.add(newPage).subscribe(...)`.

Now since you also want to do stuff in your PagesService after the POST request has succeeded, you can *spy* on the result of the observable without affecting it using `tap` operator, like so:

PagesService:

```
public add(page): Observable<any> {
 return this.httpClient
  .post('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts', page)
  .pipe(
     tap(() => {
        this.pages.push(page);
        this._pages.next(this.pages);
     }),
  );
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. I knew it was something like this just couldn't for the life of me work it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update pages array on same page, use _pages observable instead of local variable page. you need to do only three changes.

```
<p>
  In the real life example there will be multiple subscribers to the pages array on the pages service.  When I add to the array, i need to contact the backend server as well as, update the array so the subscribers can pick up the change.  
  </p>
  <p>
  As well as updating the array, it would be nice for the component thats submitting the call to know when the save has completed.  This way i can display some visual information to the user.  In this example i use the isSaving variable.  This is the part i dont know how to handle, i want to add to the pages array, but also have the component subscribe to the http call so that it can do some stuff once the call is complete.
  </p>
  <p>

  Number of Pages: <strong>{{(pagesService._pages | async).length}}</strong> <br />  <br />
  <button (click)="addPage()" [disabled]="isSaving">Add Page</button>
</p>
```

set private to public to _pages variable into service.

```
public _pages = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
```

and 3rd changes in need to update isSaving variable.

```
public getPages() {
    this.pagesService.get().subscribe((result: any[]) => {

      this.pages = result;
this.isSaving = false;
    }, error => {

      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

I have tested all scenario and it's working fine.
Let me know if you have any query.
Thanks.